# Stack overflow Exception on Hibernate Mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:708)
```

This is the Exception I am getting when use Find Method .
I am using Spring Boot JPA Repository.

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name ="Store")
public class StoreEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long store_id;
private String storeDescription;
private String storeName;
private String lattitude;
private String longitude;
private boolean isActive;
private boolean is247;
private Date createdDate;
private Date lastModifiedBy;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "store", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ="store", allowSetters=true)
private Set<GroceryItemEntity> groceryItem;
```

@Table(name ="Grocery")
public class GroceryItemEntity {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long grocery_id;

private String name;
private String description;

private double price;
private boolean isActive;
private Date  createdDate;  
private Date  lastModifiedBy;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ="groceryItem", allowSetters=true)
private StoreEntity store;
```

Part of Exceptions

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:708)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
```

Comment: Nice exception. Now it needs a question and some code to be a worthy post.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Please Check the Code.

Comment: Which find method?

Comment: FindAll() or findOne(id) of jpa repositories

Comment: You have an infinite recursion problem when when attempting serialization - each `StoreEntity` has a reference to a set of `GroceryItemEntity` instances and vice versa. `Jackson` provides a set of annotations (`@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, and `@JsonManagedReference`/`@JsonBackReference`) to work around this problem in various use cases. You just have to evaluate and figure out which one best meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks @TheHeadRush ,You are absolutely Right.Its My Mistake to expose the entity class in Endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ="groceryItem", allowSetters=true)
```

Used in All Mapping to fixed the issue of infinite recursion.

Actually I changed the Structure of my application.Used Vo in Endpoint instead of Entity Class